# Jekyll generator plugin - Create file and output data

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I'm trying to get my Jekyll generator (ruby plugin) to create a JSON file on build and output a hash into it.

At the end of my generator I have the following code to create the file (which is where the build fails):

```
json = JSON.pretty_generate(publicLocations)
File.open("_data/public_locations.json", 'w') { |file| file.write(json) }

json = JSON.pretty_generate(privateLocations)
File.open("_data/private_locations.json", 'w') { |file| file.write(json) }
```

When building the site I get the following error:

```
jekyll 3.8.4 | Error:  No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - _data/public_locations.json
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to create a file and output data to it?